# Suspicious website with misleading URL shows SO in a frame and puts ads over it

Tags: discussion, copycat-sites

I was searching for some problems with Google, when I found this website among the results:

`http://stackoverflow.com.mevn.net`

Basically, all this (supposedly Vietnamese) website does is displaying SO in a frame and putting non-related ads over it. If that's not enough, the URL is completely misleading and you can easily think that it's the official SO website you are looking at for a moment.

[image: Fake SO website's homepage]

I noticed that this suspicious website gets a surprisingly good rank in Google's search results (this is from the first page and this happened with me for multiple times):

[image: Google search result]

I know that SO/SE deals with content crawling and blatant stealing all the time, but this is a new low (especially because it even tricked Google's algorithm).

**UPDATE:** I reported the site by following the steps in the duplicate question’s answer.

Comment: The ads appear because you are not signed in there. SO does that as well (until reaching 200 rep or something similar)

Comment: My antivirus says that that's a malicious site.