# Thank-you email after reporting a content crawler website has no horizontal margin

Tags: bug, design, email

I just [reported a website](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/360030/3151675) that imitates itself being SO. After I sent the report, I received a template thank-you email, which looked like this:

[image: Thank-you email with no horizontal margin - left side]

[image: Thank-you email with no horizontal margin - right side]]

As you can tell, the text did not have a horizontal margin.

It's *definitely* not a huge issue, but an issue nonetheless.

Comment: FYI.. your actual name is present in the first image it seems.. _in case you didnt intend to post it_..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had received the same automated mail after reporting a site.

This looks like it is intended.
See below screenshot. Both margin and padding are set to 0 in style.

[image]

But it looks fine in my email client which seems to be centering the content:

[image]

I think this has more to do with email client being used.

Comment: To be fair, we only ever tested this in Gmail on desktop, so not a lot of thought actually went into those styles ending up there. The only real goal was for it to be as unstylized as possible - no clutter and straight to the point. ;) We weren't aware that there were actually clients out there that render the message right up against the border. We might revisit it, might not. We'll see.

Comment: This circle seems like something you drew in a vector graphics program with *too much* precision, then realized that you'll post it on Meta and made it more "freehand-y".

Comment: @the4kman nooo. I used freehand from the beginning :p. Ordinary preview app in mac.. no vector graphics